# Regexp - recognize trailing 0 for decimal numbers?

Tags: sql, regex

I need a regular expression which can find a trail of "0" in the decimal space.
F.e. following format should be recognized:
1.0
1.00
1.000
etc...

Is there somekind of "wildcard" for that?
Any idea?

Thanks,

KS

Comment: Simply `like '%.0%'`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following regular expression that matches trailing zeros on the end of any decimal. Note that this does match trailing zeros in the case where there is a meaningful decimal value, but zeros occur after.

https://regex101.com/r/BJvLrO/1/

When working with regex, it is very valuable to always use a tool like https://regex101.com or https://regexr.com. Both of these tools will help you truly understand the Regular Expression. Try hovering your mouse over the different elements of the regex in my example and the tool will describe each part. You can also read the "Explanation" section to on the right side.